# How to make AQuery images load when targetSdkVersion is API 28?

Tags: targetsdkversion

When targetSdkVersion = 27, the AQuery URL images load good.
But when it equals 28, the images don't load and the image loading place holder is shown.
Any ideas how to solve this so that I can target API 28?

Comment: i have same problem have you find any solution ? please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I added

```
<!-- for targetsdk 28 -->
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

on AndroidManifest.xml, and AQuery now works again on targetSdk 28.